# Environment variable with newline in amazon opsworks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, environment-variables

I am trying to setup an environment variable in Amazon's opsworks with chef. This is intended to keep a private key which contains newline characters. This is not getting set correctly, and the deployment of my rails app fails due an Exception caused due to this incorrect variable.
Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using single quote, use double quote so it ll resolve your problem

Comment: okay will give it a try and let you know

Comment: @GaneshSagare I tried the above suggestion, but the newline characters are getting stripped off and I am receiving a space instead

Comment: Use regular expression for replace new line character to empty sting

Comment: @GaneshSagare thanks for the help. I am replacing the new line character as you suggested.
The below link says that the value in the environment variable can contain up to 256 characters, **which must all be printable**.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingapps-creating.html#workingapps-creating-environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only printable characters can be used as values in the environment variable in opsworks as documented in the link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingapps-creating.html#workingapps-creating-environment.

So, the only way I found was to replace the special characters as strings, and then in the application that was using this character, replace the string representation received from the environment variable with the corresponding special character.

Answer (score 1):

As @codeignitor mentioned, only printable characters can be used.

I would suggest use some printable standard encodings such as JSON or Base64 instead of inventing one new protocol by yourself that can distract your colleagues.

However, if you eventually adopted @codeignitor's solution, at least writing more comments in your source code to explain the special protocol.

Comment: im surprised this has no likes, akthough codeignitor solution is first that came to my mind